# Recommended Javascript Image preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, preloader

There are a couple of tools and [several](http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/21316-image-preloader-with-progress-bar-status/) [tutorials](http://binarykitten.me.uk/dev/jq-plugins/107-jquery-image-preloader-plus-callbacks.html) (even [some](http://farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/) including links to [github](http://github.com/farinspace/jquery.imgpreload)) on how to preloading images and other artifacts, like css and scripts. [YUI3 preloader](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/preload) seems to be the most reliable one.

Is there a better one? Are there any others that are faster (possibly through parallel loading), more usable or has better browser compatibility? Maybe one that uses jquery instead of YUI...

Comment: I've had good success with Caridy's YUI 3 Preloader -- works incredibly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the jquery preload plugin. Try this.........

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Preload

Answer (score 1):

This one is the best.

```
(new Image).src = '/path/to/image/to/preload';
```

To preload other things (thanks Daniel) you can try this:

```
document.createElement('object').data = '/path/to/resource/to/preload';
```

Comment: I've never seen this syntax. Where is it valid? If it's YUI that would be why I don't recognize it.

Comment: It's just native JavaScript. No libraries needed. It instantiates a new `Image` object then sets its `src` to the image to preload. Then the image is preloaded.

Comment: It's what Yui uses for IE version: http://www.phpied.com/preload-cssjavascript-without-execution/

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, you can use a lazy loader such as [this one](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) to only load images once they are have been scrolled and are in the viewport.

Comment: Seems simple and nice, but threw me off with "You can workaround this with" and lack of callbacks. Sure I can manually use onLoad, but it kinda defeats the benefits of using a library.

Comment: Also, if this (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html) is the demo, it somehow doesn't work on linux (firefox 3.6, chorme 5, and opera 10.6)

Comment: Tried it on Ubuntu 10.10 with Fireofx 3.6.8, *doesn't work*. Seems to have something Windows only? I'll investigate...