# Best way to preload all images and background images using jQuery

Tags: jquery, preloader

I have a website which consists of only two pages: index.php and content.php.
Both pages are pretty long and contain lots of graphics (both inline images and background images via CSS). All graphics are located in one folder (/img).

My idea is to include a preloader on my index.php. It should display a progress bar / spinner or something and only display the "real" content of index.php once all the graphics are loaded.

What is the best way to achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536162/recommended-javascript-image-preloader

Comment: All images using for background grouped into one load @ page load and in css use background-position property.